# pairwise combination from two lists with condition in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
names = ['John', 'Mike']
years = ['1980','1975']
```

My code:

```
combination = []
for n, nvalue in enumerate(names):
    for y, yvalue in enumerate(years):
        combination.append([nvalue,yvalue])
print (combination)
```

this produces:

```
[['John', '1980'], ['John', '1975'], ['Mike', '1980'], ['Mike', '1975']]
```

I want possible combination where each row has a name in a list with a year. So The first name will appear first at all iterations, followed by other names. The same year can appear with multiple names.

required output:

```
[[('John','1980')('Mike','1975')],
[('John','1980')('Mike','1980')],
[('John','1975')('Mike','1975')],
[('John','1975')('Mike','1980')]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
import itertools

names = ['John', 'Mike']
years = ['1980', '1975']

print [ zip(names, year_product)
        for year_product in itertools.product(
            years, repeat=len(names)) ]
```